# Unified accounts with AURA

Tags: substrate-node-template, evm, account, moonbeam

I want to use unified accounts for a Substrate-based EVM chain. I've looked into the mooonbeam implementation, and they are using it with a custom module `pallet-author-inherent` which is used for block authoring.

Is it possible to implement unified-accounts while using `AURA` for block authoring?

I've also checked the difference in source codes of both pallets and it turns out that `AuthorInherent` implements `FindAuthor<T::AccountId>` while `AURA` uses `FindAuthor<u32>`. Can anybody explain the difference and guide me where should I start if I want to use `AURA` instead of `AuthorInherent` for block authoring with unified-accounts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Darwinia2.0. We are doing this now.

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0

But for the session keys, it's still Sr25519. This is decided by AURA.

---

Key point: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8396.

Comment: I get this error `the trait "From<sp_core::H160>" is not implemented for "AccountId32"` when I set `FromH160` as `AddressMapping` type.

Comment: I don't know where did you get this. Some code or link would be helpful.

Comment: I'm getting this error on [this](https://github.com/Ali-Usama/EVM-Node-Template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L333) line. Appreciate your help regarding this

Comment: https://github.com/Ali-Usama/EVM-Node-Template/blob/d89811875a9093f1e042785c85a8b2fcc89ed527/runtime/src/lib.rs#L62-L67. You are still using the `AccountId32`. You should change it to `AccountId20` if you follow Moonbeam's solution.

Comment: I've updated my genesis accounts to the Darwinia style [here](https://github.com/Ali-Usama/substrate-EVM-chain/commit/16ce2be0d317482304b2e610dd6e0557e443323f#diff-f2256017c4e606a30f53708578da46675512cc1300be6542ed5f77e58af0d6dcR79), but on the polkadot explorer there are still accounts with H256 addresses, please check [here](https://ibb.co/k3s1d8P)

Comment: A new account is also created with the H256 address from the explorer instead of H160 (EVM) address.

Comment: You need to make a PR to that repo. Like this: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8396

Comment: I'm getting [this](https://ibb.co/CvPNSHB) error on the Accounts tab after adding my chain name in the __ethereumChains.ts__ file. Does it require any accountMappings too?

Comment: It looks like you didn't change some storage types. Some accountid are still accountid32.

Comment: But I've set the `AccountId` type to `AccountId20` [here](https://github.com/Ali-Usama/substrate-EVM-chain/blob/unified-accounts/runtime/src/lib.rs#L75), and used the same type in the runtime and the outer node as well. I guess I'm missing the spec file for my chain in `polkadot-js/apps/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec`, where the types of of other chains are being set I think.