# Invalid AccountId provided, expected 32 bytes, found 20

Tags: substrate-node-template, account, evm, moonbeam

I've implemented an evm-based Substrate chain (i.e. it uses the H160 address format), but when I try to open `Accounts` page on Polkadot explorer, I get this error:

`Invalid AccountId provided, expected 32 bytes, found 20`

[image: Error screenshot]

I've also added my chain in the `ethereumChains.ts` file, following [this](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8396) PR, but still I'm getting this error.

Comment: Like what I said in https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6699/unified-accounts-with-aura. I think there are some mistakes in your code. Our chain works perfectly. It lives on Rococo https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpangolin2-rpc.darwinia.network#/explorer.

Comment: I guess the link to your chain is broken. Can you please specify the `types` that you have to use in the `polkadot-js/apps/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec` ?

Comment: Use this one https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpangolin-rpc.darwinia.network#/explorer

Comment: Yes, it looks good. And how can I generate my spec types to be used in `polkadot-js/apps/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec` ?

Comment: Can you execute any extrinsic from your chain on `polkadot-js/apps`? I'm getting `UnknownTransaction::CannotLookup` on each extrinsic

Comment: IIUC, you don't need to do that. That's why we need `scale-info` in the Rust code.

Comment: Sure. That's a public testnet. We've already deployed a lot of Dapps there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142726/discussion-between-discardo-and-aurevoirxavier).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this today on our new network.

After submitting a PR to PolkadotJs, everything works well.

https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/9057

The PolkadotJs library will match your chain's spec name to check if it was in the Ethereum network list.

If not, you will get this error.

Comment: I added my chain to the Ethereum network list, but then I get [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/unknowntransactioncannotlookup-error-on-each-extrinsic) error on each extrinsic. :(

Comment: Did you update the library?

Comment: Which library? I ran the `polkadot-js` explorer locally, added my chain types in the `apps-config/src/api/spec` and added my chain name in the `EthereumChains` list. That's all. Is there anything more to this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been [fixed](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8925/commits/0b305bc1c3fa1a78ef7fb76ad89a362ca82171b6) in polkadot-js.

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/8923)

I'm not sure if it will be live yet but you could run the [apps](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps) `master` branch locally to get the changes.

Comment: facing the same issue with the `apps` master branch

Comment: What's the version number at the top right?

Comment: `apps v0.124.2-49`
   [Here](https://ibb.co/CbmB0bH) is the screenshot

Comment: Well, seems like you'll have this bug fix in your version then. Did you create your chain spec in `polkadot-js/apps/packages/apps-config/src/api/spec` yet? I don't have any other suggestions, sorry.

Comment: yeah, I'm struggling with generating that spec types for my chain. I've tried using the specs for another chain that implements the same evm accounts as in my chain, but that didn't work either