# `UnknownTransaction::CannotLookup` error on each extrinsic

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, evm, moonbeam, npos

I've implemented unified accounts in a NPoS consensus-based substrate chain, and modified the `polkadot-js/apps` accordingly as well. The transactions through metamask go through successfully, but I'm getting this (screenshot attached) error on each extrinsic performed through the `polkadot-js/apps`. These are the types that I've added to `polkadot-js/apps/packages/apps-config/src/api/typesBundle.ts`:

```
"types": [
    {
      "minmax": [
        0,
        null
      ],
      "types": {
        "AccountId": "EthereumAccountId",
        "AccountId20": "EthereumAccountId",
        "AccountId32": "EthereumAccountId",
        "Address": "AccountId",
        "LookupSource": "AccountId",
        "Lookup0": "AccountId",
        "EthereumSignature": {
          "r": "H256",
          "s": "H256",
          "v": "U8"
        },
        "ExtrinsicSignature": "EthereumSignature"
      }
    }
  ]
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: I think it has something to do with the mappings of  the types. The `Address` type should be mapped to the `EthereumAccountId` type no?

Comment: same issue with that as well @Abdulbee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it by making these changes in my runtime:

1. In the `frame_system::Config`, changed `Lookup` from `type Lookup = AccountIdLookup<AccountId, ()>;` to `type Lookup = sp_runtime::traits::IdentityLookup<AccountId>;`.
2. And changed the `Address` type from `pub type Address = sp_runtime::MultiAddress<AccountId, ()>;` to `pub type Address = AccountId;`

where `AccountId` is the `AccountId20`.

Comment: awesome, thanks for sharing this! it just helped me solve the same issue after applying AccountId20 to my chain!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)