# PolkadotJS Apps shows wrong AccountId20 on Frontier Template Node

Tags: polkadot-js, frontier, frontier-node-template, accountid

Frontier recently received support for Moonbeam's `AccountId20`:
https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/pull/1019

So now I'm trying to use this new feature on PolkadotJS Apps.
I'm running a Frontier Template Node (which now uses `AccountId20` by default), and I added the following JSON to `Settings`/`Developer` tab of PolkadotJS Apps:

```
{
  "AccountId": "EthereumAccountId"
}
```

However, the `Accounts` tab is picking up Moonbeam's pre-funded accounts (`Alith`, `Baltathar`, etc), which don't really have funds on this template:
[image]

While [the prefunded accounts for Frontier Template Node](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/88f3e7741cd2039b4d2a90f1b852a183861b6e18/template/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L91-L94), which are simply `Alice`, `Bob`, etc, don't show up at all.

For example:

- `Alith`: `0xf24FF3a9CF04c71Dbc94D0b566f7A27B94566cac`, no balance, shows up on `Accounts` tab
- `Alice`: `0xE04CC55ebEE1cBCE552f250e85c57B70B2E2625b`, correct balance, does not show up on `Accounts` tab

What are the necessary modifications (either on `github.com/polkadot-js/apps` or on `frontier-template-node`) in order to make this work out of the box?

---

edit: It was noted in the comments that this question is similar to [How do I use the AccountId20 and EthereumSignature Signer with polkadot.js.org?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/how-do-i-use-the-accountid20-and-ethereumsignature-signer-with-polkadot-js-org), however the solution proposed there unfortunately is not enough, as [`packages/apps-config/src/settings/ethereumChains.ts` already contains `frontier-template`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/e774236407e3f3249dd0c538b71428068ddf3f7c/packages/apps-config/src/settings/ethereumChains.ts#L7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the AccountId20 and EthereumSignature Signer with polkadot.js.org?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/how-do-i-use-the-accountid20-and-ethereumsignature-signer-with-polkadot-js-org)

Comment: it seems PR 8396 added a few extra chains to ethereumChains.ts, which already contains frontier-template... so unfortunately I think that is not enough

Comment: I'm adding some updates to this issue https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/9355

Answer (score 2):

On [Jaco's comment](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/9355#issuecomment-1517282414):

1. The type lookup doesn't work because in Polkadotjs is hardcoded to the `account` namespace (`account::AccountId20`) - which is Moonbeam's - and in Frontier the type is declared in `fp_account::AccountId20`.
2. The Alith, Baltathar.. accounts are also hardcoded for ethereum-like chains in Polkadotjs.

To solve this:

- PR polkadotjs to add `fp_account` namespace [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/abdc50f405e6d7b64c8a5f9c98371595a7d47c8f/packages/types/src/metadata/PortableRegistry/PortableRegistry.ts#L423)
- PR frontier to add Alith, Baltathar etc to genesis pre-funded accounts.